# Whaetever file I try to open with excel it launches the same macro on a previous file that I did, IM LOST

Tags: excel, vba

How can I invert this problem, I didn't touch the code but I don't know maybe while saving the file. I can't open any files anymore because it keeps opening the same macro.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The macro is likely stored in your personal workbook. Personal workbooks open every time you open excel which would explain why it looks like this macro is "haunting you from the dead".

You can read about personal workbooks here. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566

Comment: Thank you!Someone used my computer and complement macro was activated, once i unchecked it everything went fine. Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the complement macro?  I don't think I'm familiar with that....

Comment: i'm translating french into english so maybe on excel in english it has another name. it's a button on your excel toolbar that you can set the macro you want to lauch everytime you open a file